# Most efficient way to export rows to a file?

Tags: c#, datastore

So I am using a DWNet.Data Datastore for this code. After doing a retrieve my goal is to save that data to a file, however the way I am doing it seems highly inefficient as I'm exporting row by row and doing a replace 4 times.

```
using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
{
   for(int i = 0; i < datastore.Count; i++)
   {
       Thread[id].rows = i;
       sw.WriteLine(datastore.ExportRowAsString(i).Replace("\"","").Replace("null","").Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", ""));
   }

   sw.Close();
}
```

The reason for the 4 replace statements is that's the best way I've found how to format the file in the required way. First replace statements gets rid of the quotes - because every string with a column is in quotes, 2nd replace gets rid of null, the last two statements get rid of the space between rows and tab before each column.

without replace

```
"row1column1"        "row1column2"        "row1column3"        "row1column4"

"row2column1"        "row2column2"        "null"               "row2column4"
```

with replace

```
row1column1 row1column2 row1column3 row1column4
row2column1 row2column2 row2column4
```

I would leave this as is if i wasn't working 400k rows, takes a bit longer than what I would like to. Is there a more efficient way for this to be done?

Comment: Is there some logic behind this output format? Why not output in a CSV format and use a standard library to help you do that?

Comment: That's just how I was told the output format needs to be. I'm first saving it as a .temp file and then later on converting it to a .txt. Maybe I can try saving it as .csv instead of .temp.

Comment: What is the type of the `datastore` object? It looks like each row contains an object. Is it a generic `DataStore<T>`? There probably is a simpler way, but it's hard to tell without knowing what the type of the data is in each row.